# Scaling outliers in a dataset and reverse scaling

Tags: regression, outliers, multidimensional-scaling, law-of-large-numbers

I have a data set with lots of small integer values and occasional large integers. For instance 1,1,1,3,2,1,**320**,2,3,4. I would like to scale my outlier values such that I can perform regression on my data. The conditions for rescaling are - I need only integer values and the transform must be reversible. ie if I scale 1,1,1,3,2,1,**320**,2,3,4 to something like 1,1,1,3,2,1,**20**,2,3,4 then I should be able to get back to my initial data 1,1,1,3,2,1,**320**,2,3,4.

I have tried finding the mean and the standard deviation, then subtracting a multiple of the mean from my outlier. Could you recommend something else I could try?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this sort of question without knowing anything about the variables, what they represent, and what you want to do with them.
There are many different things you could do here, but whether or not they would be valid transformations for any statistical analysis depends on what you want to do with them.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, it's easy to see that your requirements 1) integer values 2) reversible transformations 3) big to small numbers; are not simultaneously possible to satisfy.